# Ruby on Rail - Format for fetching and displaying Dymanic drop down

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 tables: `Student`, `Subject` and `Score`.
Every student can add 3 Subjects (Physics, Mathematics and Chemistry) marks.
The combination of `(student_id + subject_id)` is added to `Score` table. I.e., capturing that sudent '1' has added 'Mathematics' marks with the actual score (say 0-100 range)

> ```
> student id :    subjectid     Score
>     1           Mathematics    95
> ```

The `Add` page of `Score` has a "subject" drop down. which is displayed from "subject" table.

When the student wants to add the 2nd subject marks, in the add page, he should not be displayed the previoys added subject in the drop down.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it in the following way (Rails 3.0):

```
class Subject
  scope :not_enrolled_in, lambda{ |user| where("NOT EXISTS(SELECT id FROM scores WHERE user_id = ? AND subject_id = subjects.id)", user.id) }
end
```

Or this way in Rails 2.x:

```
class Subject
  named_scope :not_enrolled_in, lambda{ |user| { :conditions => ["NOT EXISTS(SELECT id FROM scores WHERE user_id = ? AND subject_id = subjects.id)", user.id] } }
end
```

You can then get a list of subjects the current user has not enrolled in this way:

```
Subject.not_enrolled_in(current_user).all
```

You can then use this list in your select HTML code.

Comment: Am so sorry. As I am new to this, it will be great if you mention in which file I need to add these.

Comment: The scopes - the first example if you are using Rails 3 and the second if you are using Rails 2 should be inside your app/models/subject.rb model definition file. The final line is up to you - it depends on which controller and view you want to display your results in.